# Return an iterator range (subset of a main list)

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, iterator, std

I would like to code a method capable of returning a range of iterators to represent a subset of a bigger list.

Can such "subset" not have being made of contiguous objects ?

For example, if I have a std::list with n objects.

eg.

```
| object1 | object2 | object3 | object4 | ... | objectn
```

Can I return a range of iterators (a pair of begin / end we can call ItBegin and ItEnd) which would include only Object 1,3 and 4 ?

eg.

```
| object1 | object2 | object3 | object4 | ... | objectN
     ^                   ^         ^                      ^
     |                   |         |                      |
   ItBegin           ++ItBegin ++ItBegin                ItEnd
```

Is that possible or do I need to copy the objects (or use pointers to avoid the copy) onto a new list and return that list ?

Please note that the iterator(s) subset would just be used for reading. (a pair of const_iterator would do the job)

Thanks!
Giacomo

Comment: iterators iterate following a specific iteration order. so, you may 1) write custom iterators that iterate the same collection using a specific "subset" selection algorithm, or 2) create "subset" collections with only the elements you need.

Comment: If you, instead of `std::list`, had a container with random access, your method could return a vector of indices, for example. Another option is to sort the container so that the elements you need are stored contiguosly.

Comment: to add on my own comment, if you're worried about memory consuption, remember that your subset collections may contain only the object references, not object copies!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind using Boost, you could use [filter_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html), e.g.

```
struct ShouldIncludeChecker
{
    bool operator()(const Object& obj) const
    {
       return obj == object1 || obj == object3 || obj == object4;
       // ^ Customize this to fit your need.
    }
};

typedef boost::filter_iterator<ShouldIncludeChecker, std::list<Object>::iterator>
        filter_iterator;

ShouldIncludeChecker checker;
std::list<Object>::iterator old_begin = the_list.begin();
std::list<Object>::iterator old_end = the_list.end();
filter_iterator new_begin (checker, old_begin, old_end);
filter_iterator new_end (checker, old_end, old_end);

for (filter_iterator it = new_begin; it != new_end; ++ it)
{
   // read *it
}
```

---

Also, if the thing you are reading to can be made into an output iterator, you could just use `std::remove_copy_if`.